# Is it safe to call XCTestExpectation fulfill method on background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

I am using `XCTestExpectation` in a lot of tests and sometimes (very randomly) some expectations are not fulfilled (although I am sure they should be).

While investigating this problem I have noticed that some expectations are fulfilled in a main thread and some are fulfilled in a background thread. And so far these problems are with the ones fulfilled in a background thread.

Is it safe to fulfill expectations from a background thread? I could not find any explicit information about that.

Below is an example of how I use `XCTestExpectation`:

```
__block XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"test"];

[self doSomethingAsyncInBackgroundWithSuccess:^{
    [expectation fullfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    expectation = nil;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Timeout Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: You really should synchronize your interaction with `XCTestExpectation` to avoid race condition present in the above code, but I personally suspect that the problem rests elsewhere. You can confirm this by temporarily adding some `NSLog` statements and watch the timestamps and I suspect you'll find that your expectation timeout block really is getting called before your asynchronous method's completion block is called.

Comment: I really doubt that fulfilling an `XCTestExpectation` from the background thread is unsafe. The whole point of `XCTestExpectation`s are to run asynchronous tests.

Answer (score 4):

It's not documented anywhere that XCTestExpectation is thread-safe. due to there being no official documentation on the matter you can only guess by creating test examples:

```
- (void)testExpectationMainThread;
{

  __block XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"test"];

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [expectation fulfill];
  });

  [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:2 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
  }];

}

- (void)testExpectationStartMainThreadFulfilBackgroundThread;
{

  __block XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"test"];

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, kNilOptions), ^{
    [expectation fulfill];
  });

  [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:2 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
  }];

}

- (void)testExpectationBackgroundThread;
{
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, kNilOptions);

  __block XCTestExpectation *expectation;


  dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"test"];
  });

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue, ^{
    [expectation fulfill];
  });

  [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:2 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
  }];

}
```

---

Here it does not crash or cause a problem however due to the lack of official documentation it is probably safer to stick to the same queue to fulfil.

---

you should really be stubbing the method `doSomethingAsyncInBackgroundWithSuccess` and provide the app with local "dummy" data.

Your unit tests should not rely on network as it is something which is variable.

---

You should be executing the completion block of `doSomethingAsyncInBackgroundWithSuccess` on the main thread (or at least provide a way to call back consistently on the same thread), you can easily do this with GCD.

```
- (void)doSomethingAsyncInBackgroundWithSuccess:(void (^)(void))completion;
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completion();
  });
}
```

---

or use NSOperationQueue mainQueue

```
- (void)doSomethingAsyncInBackgroundWithSuccess:(void (^)(void))completion;
{
  [NSOperationQueue.mainQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    completion();
  }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the expectation I have problems with is not related to network calls. This is an asynchronous operation but does not perform network operations. I know I can switch to main thread and I will try this. The problem is that I am not sure if fulfilling in a background thread is explicitly forbidden and if this is the root of this problem. I am just guessing that this might be a problem unfortunately. Maybe you also had similar problems and this dispatch to main fixed this?

Comment: @Piotr it's not documented anywhere that XCTestExpectation is thread-safe

Comment: Well, you are right. Maybe this means it is not. I will try to dispatch to main thread and hopefully the problems will disappear.

Comment: @Piotr I have added some example test cases - you can use these to validate any claims you might have for your code.